# JSS7 - TC-CONTINUE: No dialog/transaction for id:

Tags: java, apache-camel, restcomm, mobicents, ss7

We are working on SS7 CAMEL application. The application is based on jboss 5.10GA
and Mobicents/Restcomm's jss7 and Restcomm's CAP Resource adapter.

In our Sbb we receive InitialDP message and delimiter from switch. After we recieve the delimiter we try to send connect message to the switch.

Unfortunatelly, when we invoke .send() method on the dialog that we receive in onDelimiter method, no message to switch is sent and what we can see in the jboss log is:

TC-CONTINUE: No dialog/transaction for id: 67793592

```
    public void onDelimiter(DialogDelimiter delimiter, ActivityContextInterface aci) 
    {
        try
        {
            CAPDialogCircuitSwitchedCall dialog = (CAPDialogCircuitSwitchedCall) delimiter.getCAPDialog();
            dialog.addRequestReportBCSMEventRequest(bcsmevents, extensions);
            dialog.addCallInformationReportRequest(requestsTypes, null, null);
            dialog.addConnectRequest(new DestinationRoutingAddressImpl(new ArrayList<CalledPartyNumberCap>(Arrays.asList(new CalledPartyNumberCapImpl(new CalledPartyNumberImpl("48602465380".getBytes()))))), null, new OriginalCalledNumberCapImpl(new OriginalCalledNumberImpl(cdr.getBNumber().substring(0,10).getBytes())), null, new CarrierImpl("9191".getBytes()), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, false, false, false, null, false);
            dialog.addContinueRequest();
            dialog.send();
            (...)
         }
     }
```

If it is a problem with our sccp rules then what should be the correct sccp settings for the following addresses:

Switch:
PC: 6801,
SSN: 146,
GT: 4794733271,
AI: 18

Our server:
PC: 5100,
SSN: 146,
GT: 442080000100,
AI: 18

[Here's the boot.log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlhzo6iwwkqpm5w/boot.log?dl=0)

[Here's the server.log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/maiarcem0uz69q7/server.log?dl=0)

Comment: can you please share the logs?

Answer (score 2):

This message "TC-CONTINUE: No dialog/transaction for id: 67793592" means that a TC-CONTINUE primitive came to TCAP stack but no such local dialog. No processing was done and onDelimiter() method was not invoked.

The most probably reason is that the TCAP dialog was already timeed out. You need :
- either increase dialogTimeout stack options (many times because it is CAP) 
- or inside "CAPDialogListener.onDialogTimeout(CAPDialog capDialog)" invoke capDialog.keepAlive(); (this way you need to check if dialog is not kept for too long time)

Comment: When I try to register to CAPProvider I get:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at org.mobicents.slee.resource.cap.wrappers.CAPProviderWrapper.addCAPDialogListener(CAPProviderWrapper.java:71)
Here's how I create an instance of CAPProvider:

Context ctx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
CAPProvider provider = (CAPProvider) ctx.lookup("slee/resources/cap/2.0/provider");

CAPProvider that I get is an instance of CAPProviderWrapper.
Is there a way to get CAPProvider that is an instance of CAPProviderImpl or maybe I am missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Restcomm jainslee with cap RA?

Can you please attach server.log?

Br,

TN

Comment: Yes, I am using Restcomm jainslee with CAP RA. I attached the logs from jboss to the original message

Comment: Hi,Sorry for late. but the Dialog of Delimeter() was close after your application receive this message. The idea is create new Dialog and and send back

Comment: Unfortunately, in our solution the dialog can be initiated only on the switch side. So we are unable to create new dialog on out side.

Comment: I think Delimiter message come in a TCAP-END so the dialog closed and you can't send back any other message. Can you check it in your pcap file